# VB.NET Call Setter from within Getter

Tags: vb.net, properties, setter, getter

I have a class like this:

```
Public Class MyClass

Private _intList As New List(Of Integer)
Private _avg As Decimal

Public Sub Add(ByVal anInt As Integer)
    _intList.Add(anInt)
End Sub

Public Property Avg() As Decimal
    Get
        Dim _sum As Integer = 0
        For Each anInt In _intList
            _sum += anInt
        Next
        Avg = If((_intList.Count > 0), _sum / _intList.Count, _avg)
        Return _avg
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        If _avg <> value Then
            _avg = value
            Console.WriteLine("Value changed")
        End If
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

The Getter is calculating average and calls Setter to save the value. For some reason I cannot understand, the average is always 0. For example:

```
Dim c As New Class2()
c.Add(1)
c.Add(2)
c.Add(3)
Console.WriteLine(c.Avg.ToString()) ' This will print 0
```

Did I do something wrong? What is the cause of this?

Comment: what is the value of Avg after you run: If((_intList.Count > 0), _sum / _intList.Count, _avg).

Comment: @Dan Tao's answer is correct but I hope this is just sample code because `Avg` should be a readonly property that just returns `_avg`. You can add a "dirty bit" in the `Add` method to recalc `_avg` but otherwise there isn't a reason to publicly expose a setter property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design and explicitly mentioned in the Visual Basic Language Specification, chapter 9.7.1:

> A special local variable, which is implicitly declared in the Get
>   accessor body's declaration space with the same name as the property,
>   represents the return value of the property. The local variable has
>   special name resolution semantics when used in expressions. If the
>   local variable is used in a context that expects an expression that is
>   classified as a method group, such as an invocation expression, then
>   the name resolves to the function rather than to the local variable.
>   For example:

```
ReadOnly Property F(i As Integer) As Integer
    Get
        If i = 0 Then
            F = 1    ' Sets the return value.
        Else
            F = F(i - 1) ' Recursive call.
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

Solve your issue by assigning the _avg field directly.  Property getters with side-effects like this is best avoided.

Comment: +1. The design choice is for backwards compatibility with VB6 and earlier versions, when this was the only way to return a value from a `Property Get` (the `Return` statement was added in VB7)

Answer (score 7):

Wow, I think you've discovered a *very* strange behavior of VB: when you are inside the definition of a function, you can return a value *either* with `Return` *or* by using `=` to "set" the function's value.

Like this:

```
Function GetInteger() As Integer
    GetInteger = 5
End Function
```

In the above function, the line `GetInteger = 5` is basically equivalent to `Return 5`*.

OK, so you probably already knew that. But here's the weird part, and I had no idea this was the case until testing it just now (admittedly, on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), but I am seeing the same behavior you are): apparently **this applies to property getters as well**. So look at this line:

```
Avg = If((_intList.Count > 0), _sum / _intList.Count, _avg)
```

You're actually **not calling the property setter there**; you're setting the *return value* for the getter. You can verify this by removing the line `Return _avg`; suddenly you will see your getter starts returning the actual average.

<sub>*Not *exactly* the same, as you could later set `GetInteger` to something else without returning immediately whereas using `Return` ensures the function returns right away.</sub>

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1):

Your setters and getters really should just be returning properties, and not doing the calculations themselves. Try creating a method like `calcAvg()` that does the average calculations, and on the `Add()` call that method (which should internally not re-perform the whole average calculation, but simply update it. Let me know if you're not sure how to do that). That `calcAvg()` method will set the `_avg` instance variable.

Also, I'm not sure it really makes send to have a setter for the average. An average of numbers is a derived property, not something that should be set by an external user.

Answer (score 0):

MrDanA answer is more correct than what I'm going to give you, however, I believe the reason why you are getting the value of 0 is because you are never setting the variable _avg to anything. After you do your AVG calculation if you do:

_avg = AVG
return _avg

I get a value of 2 when I do this.

Like I said before though...  MrDanA's answer is a better way to go.